# Resolve my domain to the IP address of another domain

Tags: website, domain, nameserver

I have a domain mysite.com with access to set any nameserver. I want to point it to the IP address which is behind mysite.xy.com, because the ip address is dynamic, but this url always is updated with the new IP.

Is it possible with some free dns hosting service? I already have a personal hosting, so a paid hosting is not what i want.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your DNS provider allows you to set CNAME records, use that:

```
mysite.com.   CNAME  mysite.xy.com
```

If you can afford to run your own nameserver on the hosting you already have, you could use it as the authority for the domain, and set up the above mentioned record in your zone, but that goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Great... I didn't knew it's that simple... is there any free service where I can set this, because the host of my site has no dns provider. Then I can change the nameserver of mysite.com to that free dns provider.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not certain I understand your question, but if your issue is that you are hosting a website using a domain name you acquired, mysite.com, at a location with an IP address that may change, i.e., one assigned by the [Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), then a common way to deal with that problem, so that others can access mysite.com even when its IP address has changed, is to use a [Dynamic DNS Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS). The way a DDNS service ensures that a system with a DHCP-provided address is accessible to others even when its IP address changes is that you install software on your system that communicates with the DDNS service, or you configure a router/firewall that sits in front of the system hosting mysite.com to send its IP address to the DDNS service provider periodically, so that the DDNS service knows the current IP address of the system hosting mysite.com. You then set the [Domain Name System (DNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) servers for mysite.com through your domain registrar to point to the DNS servers utilized by the DDNS provider. So whenever someone puts mysite.com in his or her browser address field, his/her system attempts to look up the IP address for mysite.com, one of the DDNS service provider's DNS servers are queried and returns the current address assigned to the system hosting your mysite.com website.

I use [No-IP.com](http://www.noip.com/) for that type of service, but there are other such services you can use, e.g., [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/remote-access/). No-IP allows you to point to any of several domain names they own for free, e.g., you could use mysite.ddns.net, etc., but if you want to use your own domain name, e.g., mysite.com, then you have to pay a yearly fee. Though I presume, you could follow b0fh's suggestion and use a DDNS service to have mysite.ddns.net equate to the IP address for the system hosting your website at the DHCP-provided address and then set up a [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) record through your domain registrar, if they provide free DNS service, which is common, to point to mysite.ddns.net.

Comment: Thanks... more precisely I already have ddns (mysite.xy.com), I just want the nameserver of mysite.com to use that ddns